# Mulesoft Netsuite - List/Search all custom field values available in Netsuite

Tags: mule, netsuite, mulesoft

**Mule 3.x**

I am trying to list/search all custom field values available in Netsuite.

There is a custom field called `custitem_ct_itemcategory`, below is metadata about this field:

```
{"name":"Item Category","internalId":"685","externalId":null,"type":"ITEM_CUSTOM_FIELD","scriptId":"custitem_ct_itemcategory"}
```

And I need to list down all the records against this custom field.
Please help, how I can retrieve record of this custom field in Mule 3.x

**Note:**

I am using below wsdl in Mulesoft for talking to Netsuite:
https://.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/wsdl/v2017_1_0/netsuite.wsdl

Answer (score 0):

FYI--that WSDL is *really* old.  You should consider a newer one.  Here is the documentation for the custom list endpoint with the SOAP API:  https://www.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2017_1/schema/record/customlist.html .  You can access it using get with the internalid of the customlist, which you can find in Setup > Customization.

Comment: I am trying with below code, and it is giving me empty array []




%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
{
 basic: {
  internalId: {
   operator: "ANY_OF",
   searchValue: [{
    internalId: "685"
   }]
  }
 }
} as :object {
 class : "com.netsuite.webservices.setup.customization.CustomListSearch"
}